# Colours appearing different on iPhone 6 plus using UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

I have a PNG image that I am re-colouring at runtime:

```
logo.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
logo.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

This appears white on my iPhone 6, all the simulators etc; but it is a slightly darker grey colour on an iPhone 6+. Could there be a reason I've missed?

Here's a screenshot of the iPhone 6+ (all the navigation items should be white - like every other device)

[image: 6+ screenshot]

Comment: in context it is definitely not white

Comment: Can you show your code relevant to those navigation items?

Comment: paste some code and add screenshot of diff. devices

Comment: Can you show how you're adding this logo in you nav bar? Also would be great if you can send the one image set

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> barTintColor is made translucent by default unless you set the
>   translucent property to NO.

Try this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```